# Mutli-instance vs Single-instance for web application

Tags: php, web-applications, multi-tenant

I am going to build a sales and finance web application. Application will contain some sensitive information of customers. So, I decided to go with Isolated approach for DB and keep their databases separate. But, I am confused between single instance and multi instance of application. Let me give some details about my application.

1. There will be regular updates for application for example new features will be added in future.
2. Each customer will have an option to purchase all modules in an application or he can choose particular modules that are useful for him. So, in this way each customer can select any module that we are offering for e.g. he can purchase 2 modules or he can purchase all of them.
3. There is a customization option too. Customer can ask for adding a new module that fulfill his needs but, of course there will be few restrictions too.
4. Each customer will have separate urls.
5. There will be a products module where user can add his products (**Note: this is not an e-commerce site**) and each customer will be from different industry so their products specification requirements will be different. For example: If one customer is from cosmetics industry so his product entities will be lets say name, color, quantity and if another customer is from food industry and selling cookies his product entities will be name and flavor. So, in this case if I keep single instance of application for all, then, how could it be possible for me to give each customer the product module with different fields.

So, for such application I am thinking to go with single instance application i-e one instance of application for all but I would like to take experts advice.

Please suggest me what will be right and most efficient option for my application.

Thank You.

Comment: `I am going to build a sales and finance web application.` and then you got stuck when you thing about the implementation of that! Only one question: Do you want to code this hole thing by yourself or do you maybe want to use a framework like sympony?

Comment: Its not decided yet, I am working on it and will go with the option that will be best. What do you suggest , framework will be a good option? I am not stuck I just want to go with the option as when I was working on its architecture I came across with two options that I mentioned in my question so I just need an expert advice.

Comment: Dont really know what you are want to do, but when i hear something like `build a sales and finance web application` and not one line of code is written,it sounds like: I want to build a car from nothing on my own. There are so many topics to disscus, if you want to do something like an application. Please look what a framework can do for you, so you dont have to code all that stuff by yourself. Can i ask how long do you thing you need to get your first working stage?

Comment: I think deciding the infrastructure of your application is one of the basic step in development of a project. Without deciding the main structure of my project how can I just start writing the code. The answer to your question I think I will need 15 days - 1 month to get my first working stage.

Comment: Ok let me clear your confusion and change the sentence build a sales and finance application to I have a project of sales and finance but it has not started yet. Sorry, if my first sentence confused you.

Comment: Im a PHP developer for some years now, and `Mutli-instance vs Single-instance` is never a topic. And i tryed to google it with PHP togehter and not really a result for that combination.  Maybe i only thing the answer to your question is way to large for discuss it here on SO.

Comment: Ok thanks for your time.

Comment: Single instance and multi instance of classes is a topic in PHP, but that is more about how to code someting, not how to implement stuff. Hopefully someone get to your question with better knwolege of multi instance  applications that can give you a direction here, :) Good luck

Comment: Oh I think I confused you. I am not asking about instance of classes. Its about multi-tenancy and multi-instance architecture. you can find the difference between them on wikipedia. But anyways thanks for your comments. Thank you :)

Comment: You didnt, i just say that in PHP single/multi instance is used relativ to creating a class. Like: Are more or only one instacne of a class alowed. And you ask for single/multi instance application, but thats not really a topic if you are using PHP for a webside/application.

Comment: Ok. thanks so much but I came across few questions like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495407/multiple-instances-for-applications-one-for-each-customer and they are asking about the multi-instance application and they have PHP based application.

Comment: Please can you help me with point# 5 in the question and please ignore that single/multi instance thing for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your product module, the solution is to let your users configure thereselves their products:

Your product entity would include all common attributes that exist for each product (likely the name, maybe something else).

Then for all specific fields, create an intermediary entity which keep those fields.

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $customFields;

    // ...
}

class CustomField
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $fieldName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $fieldValue;

    // ...
}
```

In this way, your customers will define what are their product's properties, and you just display the fields by iterating over the `$customFields` array.

I think it's the easiest way to achieve what you want to do for the product module.

Comment: Thanks a lot. this is what I was looking for. +1

Comment: You're welcome. About the single/multi-instance question, both are viable, it is up to you (and your project), but then your architecture will not be the same if you choose to go on a single or multi instance application.

Comment: Sorry, can you please explain what does it mean **your architecture will not be the same if you choose to go on a single or multi instance application** ? I am sorry but I didn't get your point.

Comment: I mean, you will design your application in a way if you're going to offer a single instance app, and in another one if it is for a multi-instance one. For example, in a multi-tenant app you'll have one database for each of your customers, but in a single-instance app you can have just one database doing the work.

Comment: Yes, exactly. My app is for multi-tenants. Thanks for the answer again.